# Numbering the figures in the appendix with the section number/letter but not in the text itself

Tags: floats, numbering, appendix

I've made a latex document (`article`), and I have some pictures in my text itself but I also have pictures in my appendix (that I made with `\appendix`). I've used this command

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
```

to number the pictures with the section number, but I want this to happen only in the appendix and not in the figures in my text. How can I do this?

Comment: Have a try: put (or move) `\counterwithin{figure}{section}` at the beginning of appendix.

Comment: thanks a lot, now it works